# NodeJS query - for loops etc

Tags: node.js, express

So I'm fairly new to nodejs and I have the following function Common.validRequest that will get run on every request that does the following:

1) Checks an array for the request api route i.e '/user/login' looks in an array for that route (Common.apiDoc()) and returns the fields the request body of that route should have in an array.

```
{name: 'user', required: true, description: 'Users login ID', minLength: 5, maxLength: 7},
{name: 'password', required: true, description: 'Users login password', minLength: 7, maxLength: 100}
```

2) For each of the fields in the array if they have 'required' set to true on the field check if the request has that field in the body, if it's not return false. (false will return a missing field error)

So the question is am I doing this all wrong?

```
Common.validRequest = function (actionUrl, body) {
    var fields = Common.apiDoc(actionUrl).fields;
    if (!fields) { return true; }   
    for(field in fields) {
        if (fields[field].required) {
            if (!body[fields[field].name]) return false;
        }   
    }   
    return true;
};
// get documentation for specified api action
Common.apiDoc = function (actionUrl) {  
    for(apiAction in Common.apiMethods) {   
        if (Common.apiMethods[apiAction].url == actionUrl) {
            var doc = Common.apiMethods[apiAction];
            return doc;     
        }
    }   
};
```

Comment: Try checking the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library [each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) function out. But I think your code is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 'blocking `for`-loop' is not necessarily bad in NodeJS.

You are correct to be concerned about it. NodeJS is single-threaded and so **any** processing is blocking other processing (without the use of worker threads, web workers, etc.). However, if the processing for a particular event is small, the V8 compiler and fast processors will handle things so quick, it looks like its all happening fast (like, real-time).

However, you need to process that data sometime. You can always break down your `for`-loops with asynchronous processing and spread things out into even smaller chuncks. (The comment about the `async` library is a good place to start.) Some conventional wisdom is "don't optimize until you have to." Get things working first, and working correctly, and then see if you can make things better. At least you'll have a benchmark (for time, and success!)

The `for`-loops you have will have a small number of fields. A 10 element loops isn't going to kill your app. Calculating fibonacci sequences recursively, probably : ) Break down the big chunks that you know are big, but you can spend a lot of time breaking down *everything* and that will delay you from actually having *something*. From the sound of it, your methods are doing what you want and in general each method's processing is small, so you are on the right track.